# Request.Form "Collection is only readonly" when trying to set text box content

Tags: asp.net

Saving the values in the Lists & works fine.

```
 abc= (ABC)(Session["xml"]);

        string ctrlStr = String.Empty;
        foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form)
        {
            if (ctl.Contains("something"))
            {
                ctrlStr = ctl.ToString();
                abc.student[0].marks[j].science.something.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form[ctrlStr]);
            }
```

Want to retrieve the values from the saved object when I click on edit button back on the respective dynamic textboxes....

```
 foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form)
        {
            if (ctl.Contains("studentname"))
            {
                ctrlStr = ctl.ToString();
                (Request.Form[ctrlStr]) = abc.student[0].marks[x].science.studentname.ToString();---Gives an error stating the collection is only readonly
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Request.Form` — like the `Request` object generally — is read-only, reflecting the fact that, by the time you are responding to a request, the request itself cannot be changed.  ASP.NET uses the values from the form POST to create server controls on the Page, and these allow you to control the values of the `input` and other form elements that are written to the `Response` object.

In your case, the `TextBox` controls are being generated dynamically, so they are not automatically bound to form values — hence your problem.  You will need to keep references to the controls when they are created (or find them afterwards using the `FindControl()` method) and set their `Text` property.

(original answer follows)

The Controls collection becomes read-only at a certain point in the construction of the page.  You have to do manipulation before that point.  I don't remember offhand when it is, but you're safe with OnLoad through OnPreRender.

Where is your code firing from?

**Update:** Okay, I see what you're trying to do.  This will be easiest if you're dealing with server-side controls (that is, controls generated by ASP.NET.  That would look like this in your `aspx` (or `ascx`):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="studentname"/>
```

Then you could update the value like this:

```
abc = (ABC)(Session["xml"]);  
studentname.Text = abc.student[0].marks[j].science.something.Value.ToString();
```

That will set the value of the studentname text box automatically without needing to search through all of the Request.Form items.  (Assuming you set `j` somewhere... I don't know the context for that.)

I can't tell for sure from your code, but it looks like you may just have a "plan HTML" input, which would look more like this:

```
<input type="text" name="studentname"/>
```

In that case, there is no simple way to update the value from your page's code, so I'd start by making sure that you're using server-side controls.

Comment: the code is firing from edit button of a gridview,i can get back the values to the textboxes from the grid, but our manager does not want that. I need to retrieve the values from the stored object into the textboxes. Can you help me with the syntax.

Comment: @Janet, okay, that's clearer.  I updated my answer accordingly.  Let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Probably i did not make much sense of what I wanted to achieve. Letme try again. I have few textboxes which are loaded dynamically on the page and I am saving the values entered by the user in my object using the first part of my code and are stored in the form of gridview on the page. Now, when the edit button is clicked i want teh values from the object to appear on teh appropiate textboxes. As the textboxes are dynamic they are not entered on the aspx page.

Comment: @Janet, if you are generating the textboxes dynamically, then you'll have to have to keep references to them (by id) and set their `Text` property that way.  Although ASP.NET uses the form POST values to create server controls that you can write to, `Request.Form` itself doesn't know about controls — it's just a read-only collection of strings.  So again, your best bet is to write to the `TextBox` objects' `Text` property while you have references to them.

Comment: @Janet, I have updated the answer and question title to be a bit more descriptive in case someone else has this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the Request.Form values with reflection:

```
Request.Form.GetType().BaseType.BaseType.GetField("_readOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .SetValue(Request.Form, false);
Request.Form["foo"] = "bar";
```

Comment: Note that "foo" is really going  to be something like ctl00$MainContent$foo

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve?

The Form collection retrieves the values of form elements posted to the HTTP request body, with a form using the POST method. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx